# Mail rejected with "Client host rejected: MX-CIDR"

Tags: email, mailgun, spf

I am trying to send mails with mailgun. My DNS config (SPF,DKIM) seems to be ok and are being validated in mailgun service. I can send mail to several users with gmail, live and most others mail providers. However, I have a problem when I sent an email for email accounts of my university.

The message is rejected with the following alert:

> **"554 5.7.1 : Client host rejected: MX-CIDR"**

My current DNS settings are:

```
TXT @ "v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all"
MX 10 mxa.mailgun.org.
MX 10 mxb.mailgun.org.
```

DKIM was validated as well. I checked my domain at mxtoolbox and the dns config pass in all tests. I did not find errors related with that alert in others questions. May someone help me to fix it?

**Update 1:**
Just some more informations:

1) I dont send, and I have absolutely no intention to send spam. I created an educational website, used by students and instructors, and they send messages sometimes between each others. I also send mail to confirm registers, recovery password, as a lot of others websites do. I only send messages to people who was agreed with my terms of service, that includes the information about my mail policy. It is a small service, I never sent more than 2,000 messages in a month (I have 800 registered users so far)

2) I do not believe I was blacklisted, mxtools verify several blacklists databases and my IP have passed in all verifications. Also, the server is not rejecting all messages from my IP, I can send messages with my personal email with the same domain, but I use different services to handle my personal inbox with my domain and the emails send by my website. So, I guess it may be a DNS record mistake.

3) I only use mailgun (or others transactional email services like mandrill or sendgrid) because it is highly recommended (and easy). I use a small VPS and it is hard to configure my own email service (I am a programmer, I am not an expert in that kind of configuration). If exists negative factors about the use of these systems, I really like to know and learn more.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because email deliverability questions are not programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

I see no evidence posted that the reason the receiving mail server is rejecting your mail is because of your SPF records.

There isn't even any evidence here that the receiving mail servers are even performing SPF checks on their incoming mail.

Can you explain why exactly you believe that this has anything to do with SPF?

Just because someone's rejecting your mail, and you happen to be messing around with your SPF records, doesn't mean that the reason for your mail being rejected is due to your SPF records.

The only ones who can tell you exactly why your email is being rejected, and what needs to be done to fix it, is the receiving mail servers' administrators, and that's who you should be asking. They are the only ones who know exactly how their mail servers are configured, and how they work. Unless it's evident from the text of the error message, and it's not, anyone else's answer will be nothing but guesswork.

And actually my guess would be that, if anything, the error message seems to suggest that they have simply blacklisted your IP address range, period, for whatever reason. I would interpret "MX-CIDR" as meaning "MX's IP address' (you can Google what "CIDR" means by yourself); i.e.: sending mail server's IP address is explicitly blacklisted from sending them mail.

Now, taking from the referenced domain's web site, I quote:

"Our software automatically manages the delivery process to give your emails the best chance of landing in the inbox."

I would think that the only type of folks who would be concerned about having "the best chance of landing in" someone inbox would be all the typical spamming parasites. I browsed through the referenced website, and I couldn't shake off a slimy feeling I get after typically wandering into a typical spam spewer.

Is this domain being used to send spam?

If so, then you probably know the answer to your question, already.

Answer (score 0):

Certain SPF libraries might reject emails when trying to perform a reverse lookup on the domain that you're sending from.

They usually get this from the MX records attached to the domain and if there's a mismatch it'll fail out with a rejection (more detail here: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/spf.html).

It's usually only a problem if the receiving server is not necessarily configured correctly, or is being super harsh on incoming mail due to an overwhelming amount of spam.